# Display all bindings of site from IIS

Tags: iis, powershell, binding, sites

Is there any powershell script or any vbscript which can display all bindings of sites from IIS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the `Get-WebBinding` cmdlet (IIS 7 and up):

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
Get-WebBinding
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
$Websites = Get-ChildItem IIS:\Sites
$site = $websites
$site.bindings.Collection
```